# What are the best way to automatize the creation of related records when the information is coming from Callouts?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, custom-object, recordtriggeredflow, relatedrecord

I want to know if there is a way to relate records when the information is coming from Schedulable callouts, I created other classes to create the first and the second list of records but now I need to relate them, for what I thought it was a good idea it was to get the record ID's from the first and second list of records

**First List of Records:** [image]
**Second List of Records:** [image]

What have tried is to get a list of those board's id's  from the first object:

```
    List<String>Boardids = new List<String>();

for(Educational_Program__c EP :[Select Boards_IDs__c from Educational_Program__c where Boards_IDs__c != null] )
{
    Boardids.add(EP.Boards_IDs__c);
}
                String commaBoardsid = String.join(Boardids, ', ');
            String Boardsidcomma = commaBoardsid.replaceAll('\\n', ', ');
        List<String>lsdt = Boardsidcomma.split(',');
```

Then with the list, I was trying to loop and perform SOQL to get the ids from the records from the first and second object to get the object and finally create the related record:

```
List<Educational_Program_Claned_Board__c> relatedEDP = new List<Educational_Program_Claned_Board__c>();
List<id> CBid  = new List<id>();
List<id> EPids = new List<id>();

for(Integer i=0; i<lsdt.size(); i++)
{
    List<Educational_Program__c>AEP = [Select id from Educational_Program__c where Boards_IDs__c = :lsdt[i]];
    
    EPids.add(AEP.id);
    List<Claned_Board__c>ACB = [Select id from Claned_Board__c where Claned_Board_Id__c =: lsdt[i] ];
    
    CBid.add(ACB.id);
   Educational_Program_Claned_Board__c wrkrelatedEDP = new Educational_Program_Claned_Board__c();
    wrkrelatedEDP.Board__c = CBid ;
    wrkrelatedEDP.Educational_Program__c = EPids;
    
    relatedEDP.add(wrkrelatedEDP);

}

insert relatedEDP;
```

But when I Executed this in Anonymous I got the Error: **Variable does not exist: id** I tried to identify the reason of the error but I was unable to identify it.

So, I created a flow to relate the records when the second list of records is created, but the flow only related those that are not in a group, is there a way to separate those values using a formula inside the flow or is going to be needed to use Apex to related all of them?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can relate them using external ids, directly when inserting them via apex : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_nested_object.htm

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.